# Algorithm for alignment guidelines/snapping found in GUI builders

Tags: java, android, user-interface, kotlin

I try to implement a behavior that is similar to many GUI builders: Currently dragged components should snap in alignment with another component if they are almost on a horizontal or vertical line with it.
My current approach is to iterate over all placed components and check if any of the four edges are (almost) aligned with an edge of the dragged component:

```
for (v in rootView.relativeLayout.children()) {
    // x
    val left = event.rawX - dXInit
    val right = event.rawX - dXInit + view.width
    val leftEdgeRange = (v.leftEdge() - 50 .. v.leftEdge() + 50)
    val rightEdgeRange = (v.rightEdge() - 50 .. v.rightEdge() + 50)

    when (left) {
        in leftEdgeRange -> x = v.leftEdge()
        in rightEdgeRange -> x = v.rightEdge()
    }
    when (right) {
        in leftEdgeRange -> x = v.leftEdge() - view.width
        in rightEdgeRange -> x = v.rightEdge() - view.width
    }
    // y
    val top = event.rawY - dYInit
    val bottom = event.rawY - dYInit + view.height
    val topEdgeRange = (v.topEdge() - 50 .. v.topEdge() + 50)
    val bottomEdgeRange = (v.bottomEdge() - 50 .. v.bottomEdge() + 50)

    when (top) {
        in topEdgeRange -> y = v.topEdge()
        in bottomEdgeRange -> y = v.bottomEdge()
    }
    when (bottom) {
        in topEdgeRange -> y = v.topEdge() - view.height
        in bottomEdgeRange -> y = v.bottomEdge() - view.height
    }
}
```

with

```
fun View.topEdge() = y
fun View.bottomEdge() = y + height
fun View.leftEdge() = x
fun View.rightEdge() = x + width
```

But this seems inefficient because this code is called in **`onTouch()`**, so this loop is run pretty often. Is there a better approach? General or Java answers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient approach would be to reduce the *O(n)* loop which iterates over all the views to a *O(log n)* search for the nearest edge in some sorted representation like a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which are [balanced binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). This, of course, requires you to store four separate sorted representations for each of `leftEdge`, `rightEdge`, `topEdge`, and `bottomEdge`.

A simple example would be (showing only `leftEdge`, the others are similar):

```
val viewsByLeftEdge = TreeMap<Int, View>()
```

To add a view into the map, just use:

```
viewsByLeftEdge[view.leftEdge()] = view
```

<sup>(note that if several views have the same left edge value, only the last one will be stored in this map)</sup>

And after that, instead of iterating over all the views, you can find the nearest left edge to a given `left` coordinate:

```
val floorL = viewsByLeftEdge.floorKey(left)
val ceilingL = viewsByLeftEdge.ceilingKey(left)
val nearestL = when {
    floorL == null -> ceilingL
    ceilingL == null -> floorL
    ceilingL - left < left - floorL -> ceilingL
    else -> floorL
}

if (nearestL in left - 50 .. left + 50)
    x = nearestL
```

Here, [`.floorKey(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorKey(K)) returns the highest edge coordinate in the map that is less than or equal to `x`, or `null` if there's no such coordinate. Similarly, [`.ceilingKey(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingKey(K)) returns the lowest coordinate in the map that is greater that `x`, or `null`.

This takes *O(log n)* time and will be faster than iterating over all the views for any significant number of views. If you don't need to get the view by its edge, simplify the code by replacing the `TreeMap<Int, View>` with `TreeSet<Int>` (the functions then are `floor(x)` and `ceiling(x)`.

It is up to you to place the maps in your code, fill them with your `View`s and compose the functions for the four edges that would fit better into your code design.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will try that today :)

Comment: Ok, what I can't wrap my head around is: what to do if one of these edges change, I can't simply remove it and add the new value, because it could possibly remove the edge of another component that had the same value. Do I need to rebuild all maps/sets from ground up if anything changes?

Comment: @Benjoyo, the easiest workaround to avoid that, I think, is to have a `TreeMap<Int, HashSet<View>>` instead of `TreeMap<Int, View>`, so that you can check and update the `HashSet` corresponding to an edge value. This, however, adds code complexity and performance overhead. Another option is to use, for example, a `TreeSet<View>(compareBy<View> { it.leftEdge() }.thenBy { it.id })` where `id` is unique. This *allows* multiple values for a certain edge value, but queries to such a map require you to construct a fake `View` with the desired left edge value and then call  e.g. `set.floor(fakeView)`

Comment: Thank you, it's working smoothly with 40+ views, all I need :)

Comment: @Benjoyo, glad that I could help!